# What are the fuller expressions of the Russian equivalents to some common festive greetings (e.g., Happy Birthday, Happy Easter, Happy New Year's)?

Tags: словоупотребление, падежи, приветствия, согласование

Even Duolingo will tell you that

> **[Greetings and other similar expressions are often shortened versions of longer phrases, where words still retain their forms.](https://www.duolingo.com/skill/ru/Phrases-1/tips-and-notes)**

When you see an oblique form (i.e., a declined form) of a phrase, it is an indicator that it is often part of a longer phrase and one in which the declination makes grammatical sense.

So, maybe if I knew the fuller expressions of these Russian phrases, they would make more sense to me.  Below you will find what confuses me about these phrases:

This latest exploration into Russian all began when I tried to figure out how to literally translate the phrase:

> **С днём рождения!**
> **Happy Birthday!**

word-for-word/literally.  I then wondered why the "c" was even used at all.
I then realized I really didn't know for sure what the literal meaning of this phrase was.  I then noticed that

> **Happy Easter! ∼ Счастливой Пасхи!**

I got to wondering, *If this is a shortening of the longer phrase "I wish you a Happy Easter!"*

> Я желаю вам счастливой Пасхи!

*then shouldn't "happy easter" be in accusative case?*  *And if so, and Пасха is feminine, then why isn't Happy Easter!:*

> Cчастливую Пасху!

What case is "Счастливой Пасхи!" in?  I am assuming both words are in the same case, but if I am mistaken, please let me know that, too.

Furthermore, if a form of the word "счастливый" is used to express "Happy Easter" why isn't it used when wishing one a "Happy Birthday"?  Is Easter the only holiday that uses "счастливый" for a greeting such as this?

**Happy New Year's** appears to mirror the Happy Birthday construct with:

> **C новым год!**

but again, how does this break down literally, and why not use a form of "счастливый" to express it?

**Merry Christmas** appears to use both forms if **[Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/Merry+Christmas!)** is any indicator

> **С Рождеством!**
> **Счастливого Рождества!**

but again I'm not entirely sure about the literal breakdown or use of case.

---

Are there any other holidays Russians typically front with "Merry" or "Happy"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We commonly use two structures for congratulations and wishes:

> *• **поздравлять с** чем-то* (Instrumental)
>
> *• **желать** чего-то* (Genitive).

The case used depends on the verb, and should be learned by heart.

So *(поздравляю) с днем рождения, с Новым годом, с Рождеством, с Пасхой*.

*(Желаю) счастливого Рождества, счастливой Пасхи* (neither is quite typical for us, but both are possible), or *хорошо провести праздники*.

Languages differ as do traditions. Why should they be alike?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133809/discussion-on-answer-by-v-v-what-are-the-fuller-expressions-of-the-russian-equi).

Comment: This is all much clearer for me now.  Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score -2):

*"С днём рождения!"* - ПОЗДРАВЛЯЮ с днем рождения !

или, если совсем полно : я поздравляю тебя с днем рождения ! :).

*"C Новым год!"* (тут у вас ошибка с падежом) - с Новым Годом! - то же самое : поздравляю с Новым Годом !
*"but again, how does this break down literally, and why not use a form of "счастливый" to express it?"*
Есть и такое : "Счастливого Нового Года !" - и это пожелание, а не поздравление. :)"Желаю вам счастливого Нового Года!"

Форма "Поздравляю с ...", " с ..." применима к любому именно празднику. Но не к памятным грустным датам.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133756/discussion-on-answer-by--what-are-the-fuller-expressions-of-the-russian-eq).